# Create extension attribute to inventory source

Tags: magento2.3, module, plugin, extension-attributes, multi-source-inventory

I have a requirement to add the custom attribute (delivery_time) to each inventory source.

my-vendor/module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">=
    <type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="plugin_source_save" type="<vendor-name>\<module>\Plugin\SourceSave"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

my-vendor/module/etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_time" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

my-vendor/module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/inventory_source_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

<fieldset name="general">
    <field name="delivery_time" formElement="input" sortOrder="70">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Delivery Time</label>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

my-vendor/module/Plugin/SourceSave.php

```
<?php
namespace my-vendor\module\Plugin;

use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceSearchResultsInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceExtensionFactory;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceExtensionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\StockInterfaceFactory;


class SourceSave
{

    const FIELD_NAME = 'delivery_time';

    protected $extensionFactory;
    protected $sourceFactory;

    public function __construct(SourceExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }


    public function afterGet(SourceRepositoryInterface $subject, SourceInterface $source)
    {
        $sourceComment = $source->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
        $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setDeliveryTime($sourceComment);
        $source->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $source;
    }

    public function afterGetList(SourceRepositoryInterface $subject, SourceSearchResultsInterface $result)
    {
        $products = [];
        $sources = $result->getItems();

        foreach ($sources as $source) {
            $sourceComment = $source->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
            // echo $sourceComment;
            $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setDeliveryTime($sourceComment);
            $source->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            $products[] = $source;
        }
        $result->setItems($products);
        return $result;
    }

    public function beforeSave(
        SourceRepositoryInterface $subject,
        SourceInterface $source
    )
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->extensionFactory->create();
        if ($extensionAttributes !== null && $extensionAttributes->getDeliveryTime() !== null) {
            $source->setDeliveryTime($extensionAttributes->getDeliveryTime());
        }
        var_dump($source->getData());die;
        return [$source];
    }

}
```

[image]

The Delivery Time field is visible from the frontend, but the delivery_time value is returning NULL on the before save method which should be saved in DB

I save the delivery time extension attribute value to DB by observing

> controller_action_inventory_populate_source_with_data

```
    $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
    $requestData = $request->getParam('general', []);

    $type =  $requestData['delivery_time'];
    $sourceCode = $requestData['source_code'];

    //Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface 
    $source = $this->sourceRepository->get($sourceCode);
    $source->setDeliveryTime($type);
    $source->save();
```

But the admin UI form data is not filled up.
Kindly help me where I'm struck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your inventory_source_form.xml under `<settings>`, try adding `<dataScope>extension_attributes.delivery_time</dataScope>`.

Something like this:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

<fieldset name="general">
    <field name="delivery_time" formElement="input" sortOrder="70">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <dataScope>extension_attributes.delivery_time</dataScope>
            <label translate="true">Delivery Time</label>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to to the fix above you will need to make sure your module has dependency/sequence to ensure the form is populated.

module.xml

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_InventoryAdminUi" />
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to create de database column, with db_schema.xml, like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="inventory_source">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="delivery_time" unsigned="true" nullable="true" identity="false"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```